Byte array passthrough via Jackson ObjectMapper
I have a java openapi generated client which I use to retrieve some image from a remote server (this process runs fine against a browser, postman, etc.). I am able to configure the objectMapper of the client but I cannot switch it off (otherwise the generated client complains about null objectMapper). When I am trying to get the image, the objectMapper complains about invalid characters, because I guess it fails to interpret the image byte array as an object. I would like the objectMapper to simply pass-through the byte array to another byte array, but not try to interpret it.
The following example summarises the issue:
byte[] originalByteArray = HexFormat.of().parseHex("e04fd020ea3a6910a2d808002b30309d");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
byte[] byteArray =  objectMapper.readValue(originalByteArray, new TypeReference<>() {});

This leads to the following exception:
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x20


How can I make the byteArray to simply contain the originalByteArray with the constraint that it has to be processed by the objectMapper?
Thank you

Would a custom de/serializer that converts to/from hex suffice?

If it does the job, yes
